# Odoo - Fetch record and cast it into python object

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

In Odoo 10-e is this possible to execute a query and then cast the resultant list or tuple into a python object. Like

```
 self.env.cr.execute("SELECT * FROM res.users WHERE Id = 1")
```

In above query it would return a single record

```
self.env.cr.execute("SELECT * FROM res.users")
```

Now this query would return a list of users. Now is there any way to tell `self.env.cr.fetchall()` that i want the result as a single User object or List of Users . If not then can we cast them after fetching ?

Comment: Why not using the ORM layer instead? Sorry, but i don't see the need of bypassing the ORM layer with such an example.

Comment: @CZoellner Actually i am new to Odoo and i am unaware how can you fetch those with ORM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the ORM layer for those simple queries. There are some easy methods for this (e.g. for typical CRUD-> create, read, update, delete):

**Create** -> create(vals)

```py
# creates a user in db and
# returns this user as python object (RecordSet)
created_user = self.env['res.users'].create({'name': 'New User'})
```

**Browse** -> browse(list_of_ids)

```py
# reads the whole database rows and
# returns python objects (RecordSet)
browsed_users = self.env['res.users'].browse([1,2])
```

**Search** -> search(domain)

```py
# search database with Odoo's domain syntax
# returns python objects if something were found
domain = [('name', '=', 'New User')]
searched_users = self.env['res.users'].search(domain)
```

The examples are only touching the surface. Look into [Odoo's Developer Documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html) for more information.

EDIT: Using the ORM layer has advantages and disadvantages. But in context of Odoo there is one really big advantage: the layer has user access control integrated. And that is just one big advantage.

Answer (score 2):

You can get it with following way :

```
q = "select * from res_users where id = 1"
#q = "select * from res_users"
self.env.cr.execute(q)
res = self.env.cr.dictfetchall()
users = self.env['res.users'].browse([row['id'] for row in res])
```

Get data with dictfetchall() and with using browse() method get recordset of users.

This may help you.

Comment: That looks good, can i also do something more with this `browse` ? How can i only those users which are in `Group 1`. Assuming that `Group 1` is a valid user and there are some users in that group

Answer (score -1):

There is a way to get a result in python list object.

```
    qry = """select id from res_partner where parent_id is Null;"""
    self._cr.execute(qry)
    result = self._cr.dictfetchall() 
    user_ids=[] 
    for ids in result:
        user_ids.append(ids.get('id'))
```

In `user_ids` variable, you get all res.partner's ID.